# Changing This Row Colour On Gantt Chart

Tags: oracle-apex

I have created this Gantt chart to show the Roster screen, I need to change the format of the tasks, I mean if the task is(MG) then appears with a yellow color and if it is (MGFX) appears with orange else appears in white view, I need to change each value with custom color instead of symbols  not that the values come from TASK_NAME column from TASK_HANDLER table

Here Is The Chart:

[image: Here Is The Chart]

I am Seeking For Information about how to do it

Comment: Could you show your code that produces the result so far? I am not sure this is a programming problem, so it may transpire that the question is not on-topic here - perhaps you can give some more information on that?